# How to temporarily disable rsh between machines for user only

Tags: linux, unix, remote, remote-access

First, please note that I am just a regular user. I cannot do anything as a super user.

Our sysadmin has enabled `rsh` between machines in our local network. That is, I can do this:

```
[user@machineA] rsh machineB ls
a/  b/  c/
```

For testing purposes, I would like to temporarily disable `rsh` from "machineA" to "machineB". Here is roughly what I'm looking for:

```
[user@machineA] rsh machineB ls
Permission denied.
```

I have heard of `/etc/hosts.deny`, but I cannot write files to `/etc` given my status as a regular user.

One caveat: `rsh` still needs to be in my `PATH`. And again, I'd like this to be a temporary solution that only applies to me, a single user.

If anyone has a good idea for this, please let me know.

And before anyone mentions it; yes, I am aware that we shouldn't be using `rsh`. I am working on changing our tool to use `ssh`, but I need to keep `rsh` support for legacy compatibility. The reason I want to do this is to test how the tool responds when `rsh` is not available (but still in `PATH`). Thanks!

Comment: Don't try to bypass your sysadmin's - try to work with them instead. Get them to set up a second user maybe or to disable your access for a specific hour of the day.

Comment: Hmm... it's not that I want to "bypass" the sysadmin, it's just that editing /etc/hosts.deny will affect all users. I want this to affect *only* me so this testing doesn't disturb others. I can check if the sysadmin has the ability to make this happen for only me; however I feel that if there was a solution for this on a per-user basis, it would be available to the user, not just superusers.

Comment: There might be a user accessible option but why would it have been set up? Who else has ever asked? Probably only you so why would they have set anything up? If they are not too stressed out, they might welcome a different question for a change!

Comment: Bad news: sysadmin lives in a timezone +12 hours from me, so no help for now. Good news: I found another pair of machines that don't have `rsh` set up, so I don't need to modify anything. I will leave this question here in case anyone has an answer and it helps someone else looking for the same solution.